# Destroy Sequence after being played in Game Maker

Tags: sequence, game-maker

The Code plays an Attack Animation (Sequence) if the cooldown timer hits 0 and "Q" is pressed. The problem is, that I dont know how to delete the sequence after it has finished its animation of 12 Frames. If I use "Layer_destroy_sequence(seq)" right after playing it, it gets deleted before the 12 Frames are played. If I do not destroy it, the game starts lagging after just a few sequence plays. If I try to destroy it at the beginning of the script, I get an error message, saying, that it cannot destroy a sequence that doesnt exist.
[image]

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing more of your code. Look at the section "Sequence Layers" in the Gamemaker manual. Using the layer_sequence_exists and layer_sequence_destroy you should be able to do what you want. https://manual.gamemaker.io/monthly/en/#t=GameMaker_Language%2FGML_Reference%2FAsset_Management%2FRooms%2FSequence_Layers%2FSequence_Layers.htm&rhsearch=layer_sequence_create

Comment: thats actually the whole code. I still did not get it to work. And also Ive noticed massive frame drops after playing the sequence a couple of times (as if the sequences are not properly destroyed) and the game becomes unplayable until restart

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue myself by:

- removing the temporary var seq and using a variable thats created with the Object itself

  ```
  attack_animation = noone;
  ```
- Have the attack_animation be declared a value when the conditions are met:

  ```
  attack_animation = layer_sequence_create("Instances", x, y, sAttackLeft);
  ```
- Have the attack animation deleted as soon as its time of 12 frames ends using

  ```
  layer_sequence_destroy(attack_animation);
  ```